# distance in hilbert space about the center of two balls

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Assume H is a Hilbert space and $B_1,B_2$ are two balls with center $x_1$，$x_2$ and radius 1 for both. is the following claim right:

d($x_1$，$x_2$)=|$x_1$-$x_2$|$\geq$ 2?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: An hypothesis is clearly missing. What if the two balls are equal?

Answer (score 0):

If the balls are disjoint then it is true because the line segment $[x_1 , x_2]$ has nonempty intersection with $D=H\setminus (B_1 \cup B_2 )$. Let $x\in [x_1 , x_2]\cap D$ then $$|x_1 - x_2 | = |x_1-x | +|x-x_2| >1+1 =2$$

Comment: why is the first equation true? we are in Hilbert space and please  be more specific